# Find All Subcollections of Firestore Doc Programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to programmatically access the subcollections in a document without explicitly knowing their name?  I'm essentially looking for a function similar to firestore().getCollections() but for a document rather than the root of the database.

```
db
  .collection("collection")
  .doc("document")
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      doc.getCollections().then(collections => {
        //do stuff
      });
    }
  })

//...
```

Obviously docSnapshots don't have this function, but is there any other way to achieve this?  Or do you have to know the subcollection's name ahead of time?

Comment: Currently `firestore().getCollections()` only available in admin firebase SDK, but not in the web SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

```
db
  .collection("collection")
  .doc("document")
  .getCollections()
  .then(collections => {
      //do stuff
  });
```