# Find All Subcollections of Firestore Doc Programmatically - example don't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Now i'm studying Firebase Firestore javascript web api.
I'm read tutorial and repeat example code:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

At the end of this page there is topic "List subcollections of a document" with examples for different languages.

In Node.js you can use simple call getCollections method to obtain list of document's subcollection :
db.collection('cities').doc('SF').getCollections()

But for web wrote:
// Not available in the Web client library.

At this topic author wrote that can call getCollections method:
[Find All Subcollections of Firestore Doc Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696042/find-all-subcollections-of-firestore-doc-programmatically)

What's the problem in web client javascript:

1. For this:
   let sfRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF').getCollections;
   console.log(sfRef);
   Result: sfRef is undefined
2. For this:
   let sfRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF').getCollections();
   Result: Error - getCollections is not a function

My question: 
Is there any way to obtain list subcollections of a document in javascript web client?

Comment: As the duplicate says, it's not supported in client SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

**Use collection group queries for this**
[check details here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)

```
 db.collectionGroup('YOUR SUB COLLECTION NAME')
  .where('CONDITION IF HAVE')
  .get()
```

Comment: If you know subcollection name - you can get documents in it. But my question - how to get names of subcollections ?

Comment: in query snapshot object